# DateTime.ToString Is not working for MMM in Swedish culture anymore

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I have issue with formatting date to dd MMM yyyy. when i try to format this date with Swedish culture I get date as 21 apr. 2023 where it should be 21 apr 2023 I tried below code in console app with .net core 7 and its same:

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).FirstOrDefault(c => c.LCID == 29);
Console.WriteLine(cultureInfo.LCID);
var dateString = date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", cultureInfo);
Console.WriteLine(dateString);
```

Please note this works when i run this program in Azure app service. so there must be something with my windows 11 enterprise 21H2 operating system or I am not sure where is the issue? Any help would be appreciated

I tried

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).FirstOrDefault(c => c.LCID == 29);
Console.WriteLine(cultureInfo.LCID);
var dateString = date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", cultureInfo);
Console.WriteLine(dateString);
```

I expect it to return 21 apr 2023

Comment: you could add a `var dateString = date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", cultureInfo).Replace(".","");` this would remove the unwanted dot if it was present and keep things unchanged if it came up

Comment: @DenisSchaf That would be a workaround at best. Swapnil: What are your Date Format settings in your Win 11 System?

Comment: Thanks 
No that wont work because for march in swedish it will be mars not mar. so that will stay 4 characters
but I am more looking for why its broken because it was certainly working before. I think its after i moved from .net framework to .net core but I am not sure.

Comment: agree, thats why its a comment not an answer.

Comment: When i run these commands in poswershell I get :
PS C:\Users\swalo> $C=Get-Culture
PS C:\Users\swalo> $C.DateTimeFormat

FullDateTimePattern              : dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
LongDatePattern                  : dddd, MMMM d, yyyy
LongTimePattern                  : h:mm:ss tt
MonthDayPattern                  : MMMM d
AbbreviatedMonthNames            : {Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr...}
MonthNames                       : {January, February, March, April...}
AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames    : {Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr...}
MonthGenitiveNames               : {January, February, March, April...}

Comment: @SwapnilLomate, replace the dot with a space

Comment: And this looks ok:
PS C:\Users\swalo> $FinalCulture = [Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("sv-SE")
PS C:\Users\swalo> $FinalCulture.DateTimeFormat


AMDesignator                     :
AbbreviatedMonthNames            : {jan, feb, mar, apr...}
MonthNames                       : {januari, februari, mars, april...}
IsReadOnly                       : True
NativeCalendarName               : Gregoriansk kalender
AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames    : {jan, feb, mar, apr...}
MonthGenitiveNames               : {januari, februari, mars, april...}

Comment: @SwapnilLomate You want an answer that will return 21 Mar 2023 and not 21 mars 2023?

Comment: yes because i said MMM

Comment: @Fildor it seems to be another ICU vs NLS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [.NET globalization and ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu) doc:

> Before .NET 5, the .NET globalization APIs used different underlying libraries on different platforms. On Unix, the APIs used [International Components for Unicode (ICU)](https://icu.unicode.org/), and on Windows, they used National Language Support (NLS). This resulted in some behavioral differences in a handful of globalization APIs when running applications on different platforms. Behavior differences were evident in these areas:

> - Cultures and culture data
> - ...

If you switch [back to NLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#use-nls-instead-of-icu) you should get the expected output (at least works on "my machine"). For example by adding the following to .csproj:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You should get expected "21 apr 2023".

See also - [Behavior changes when comparing strings on .NET 5+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus).

P.S.

If I understand correctly - [this line](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/5be2ea84e59e63e4d68ebcd4082996d6db3af9f0/icu4c/source/data/locales/sv.txt#L1499) is resposnible.